# Using other dictionary values to define a dictionary value during initialization

Tags: python, dictionary, initialization

Say I have three variables which I want to store in a dictionary such that the third is the sum of the first two. Is there a way to do this in one call when the dictionary is initialized? For example:

```
myDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': myDict['a'] + myDict['b']}
```

Comment: No, `myDict` does not exist before the assignment is completed and cannot be referenced.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python>=3.8's named assignment allows something like the following, which I guess you could interpret as *one* call:

```
>>> md = {**(md := {'a': 2, 'b': 3}), **{'c': md['a'] + md['b']}}
>>> md
{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 5}
```

But this is really just a fanciful way of forcing a two-liner into a single line and making it less readable and less memory-efficient (because of the intermediate dicts). Also note that the `md` used on the right hand side of the `=` really could be any name.

You could actually be a little more efficient and get rid of one spurious auxiliary dict:

```
(md := {'a': 2, 'b': 3}).update({'c': md['a'] + md['b']})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> myDict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> myDict["c"] = myDict["a"] + myDict["b"]
>>> myDict
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

You can not do this in 1 line, because `myDict` is not even exist while assigning to `c`